# Ruby: Restore object from its .inspect output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby, is there a way to restore the object from object's '.inspect' output?

Use case would be: I had '.inspect' output in production log, I hope to restore that object for testing because the object is difficult to be created outside production environment.

Comment: You can't do that. The `inspect` output of the class, like its `to_s` output, is whatever the developer defined it to be. For a simple class that could be all instance variables with something denoting the instance variable's name. For a big object, with a lot of variables, it might be a very reduced output of something that's most useful to differentiate one instance from another. It just depends on the developer. You can override the `inspect`/`to_s` method to be more representative, but instead I'd recommend adding the ability to serialize to/from JSON or use Marshall.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [Marshal module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Marshal.html). But please know you cannot just 'restore' objects from an entry in a production log...

> The marshaling library converts collections of Ruby objects into a byte stream, allowing them to be stored outside the currently active script. This data may subsequently be read and the original objects reconstituted.

Comment: Thank you for the input, appreciated.